# Exclude elements from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I'd like to iterate over an ArrayList of Strings:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
```

Instead of Iterating over all Items:

```
for(String a : list) {
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

I'd like to exclude the last elements of the List. Currently I use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

But I was wondering, if there is a shorter form. For example in R you could simply generate a list without the last element:

```
a = c("A", "B", "C")
a[-length(a)]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: > But I was wondering, if there is a shorter form.

Comment: You are getting a lot of answers @Edward

Comment: What do you mean by shorter form?  Your code example is one line of Java code.  How can you get shorter than that?

Comment: @Shivam: I'm waiting to accept Erans answer (2 minutes left)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `list.subList(0,list.size()-1)` to get a view of the List without the last element.

> **`List<E>` java.util.List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)**
>
> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

Comment: Always pay attention that `subList` returns a 'view' of the lis, as Eran said. So any changes to the list will be reflected. If you want to create a copy, then feed this to the constructor of a list: `new ArrayList<>(list.subList(0,list.size()-1))`

Answer (score 3):

Lists in Java have a [sublist method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) Returns a view of the portion of
>   this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex,
>   exclusive.

```
List<String> sub = yourList.subList(0, yourList.size()-1);
```

Comment: @AndyTurner my mistake, Thnsk a lot!!: :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");

    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    newList.remove(newList.size()-1);
```

Now, newList is having all elements of list except last.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 :

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1).forEach(i -> System.out.println(list.get(i)));
```

Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Answer (score 0):

There's another alternative.

You can exclude elements using iterator:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
             list.add("A");
             list.add("B");
             list.add("C");

Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String i = iterator.next();
    if(isRemovable(i)){ //your condition to remove item here
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

This way, other list isn't needed.

Comment: How is this shorter than the for loop in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

also try this response

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     list.add("A");
     list.add("B");
     list.add("C");


       System.out.println("the tetter to be deleted"+list.get(list.size()-1));

       list.remove(list.size()-1);
       for(String a : list) {
           System.out.println(a);
       }
```

}